# adding padding left to flow html: text not shifting

Tags: html, css, power-automate

I am using HTML in power automate and am using padding left function to try and shift the labels right.

However it is not working. Below is the code.

```html
<html>
  <style>
    .email-container2{
    border: 3px solid gray;
    }
    span.name { color:blue
    }
    .bottom-border{
    border-bottom: 30px solid blue;
    }
    .bottom-border1{
    border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
    }
    .underline{
    text-decoration-line: underline;
    text-decoration-color: blue;
    }
    .email-container1 {
    border: 3px solid gray;
    }
    .right{
    margin-left: 80%;
    text-align: right;
    }
    p.x1 {
    padding-left:10%;
    }
    p.x2 {
    }
    p.x3 {
    ;
    }
    p.x4 {
    text-align: right;
    }
    p.x5{
    }
    .img-container {
    text-align: left;
    height="20";   
    width="20";
    }
    .img-container1 {
    text-align: right;
    width="100";
    }
  </style>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body >
    <div class = "email-container" >
      <div  class = "bottom-border">
        <div  class = "bottom-border1">
          <div class ="content">
            <div class="row" style="width:100%">
              <div class= "img-container" style="width:50%">   
                <img src= https://careers.electronicsforu.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/tata-steel-logo.jpg alt="Airplane" >
              </div>
              <div class="img-container1" style="width:50%">
                <img src=  https://privatecdn.sharepointonline.com/tslin.sharepoint.com/sites/BoardingPass-Aviation/SiteAssets/SitePages/BoardingPass-Aviation/82731TataSteel_Aviation.jpg  >
              </div>
            </div>
            <br />   
            <div>
              <div class = "email-container1" style="background-color:powderblue;">
                <h4   align="center">
                TATA STEEL AVIATION SERVICES</h2>
                <h2 style="color:blue" align="center"> Boarding Pass</h2>
                <p   class ="x5" style="font-size:28px" ;>    Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; <u><strong><span class="name">@{items('Apply_to_each')?['Date']}</span></strong></u></p>
                <p  class ="x1" style="font-size:28px">Name: &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <u class="underline"><strong><span class="name">@{items('Apply_to_each')?['Name1']}</span></strong></u></p>
                <p  class ="x2" style="font-size:28px">Aircraft Regn: &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<u class="underline"><strong><span class="name">@{items('Apply_to_each')?['AircraftRegn']?['Value']}</span></strong></u></p>
                <p  class ="x3" style="font-size:28px">Sector: &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <u class="underline"><strong><span class="name">@{items('Apply_to_each')?['Sector']}</strong></span></u></p>
                <p  class ="x4" style="font-size:22px" >Signature: <u ><strong><span class="name">@{items('Apply_to_each')?['Signature']}</span></strong></u></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I try margin-left and it works,however on using margin-left the background color goes white. How do I use padding-left to do the same thing here.

Here is the image when I use margin-left:

[image]

Here is the image when I use padding-left

[image]

Comment: Use flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Please use HTML table

Comment: why , padding should work right?

Answer (score 1):

```css
  .email-container2 {
    border: 3px solid gray;
  }

  span.name {
    color: blue;
    text-align:left;
  }

  .bottom-border {
    border-bottom: 30px solid blue;
  }

  .bottom-border1 {
    border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
  }

  .underline {
    text-decoration-line: underline;
    text-decoration-color: blue;
    color: blue;
    text-align:left;
  }

  .email-container1 {
    border: 3px solid gray;
  }
  .table td, .table th{
    border:none !important;
    font-size:28px
  }
  .right {
    margin-left: 80%;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  .pl-10 {
    padding-left: 10%;
  }
  .img-container {
    text-align: left;
    height="20";
    width="20";
  }

  .img-container1 {
    text-align: right;
    width="100";
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
  <div class="email-container">
    <div class="bottom-border">
      <div class="bottom-border1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="row" style="width:100%">
            <div class="img-container" style="width:50%">
              <img src=https://careers.electronicsforu.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/tata-steel-logo.jpg alt="Airplane">
            </div>
            <div class="img-container1" style="width:50%">
              <img src=https://privatecdn.sharepointonline.com/tslin.sharepoint.com/sites/BoardingPass-Aviation/SiteAssets/SitePages/BoardingPass-Aviation/82731TataSteel_Aviation.jpg>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br />
          <div class="table table-responsive email-container1 w-100 pl-10" style="background-color:powderblue;">
            <h2 style="color:blue" align="center">Boarding Pass</h2>
            <table classs="border-0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="w-50">Date:</td>
                  <td class="underline w-50">2020-08-11</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Name:</td>
                  <td class="underline">Sandeep</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Aircraft Regn:</td>
                  <td class="underline">VT-TFA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Sector:</td>
                  <td class="underline">NoiDa</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Signature:</td>
                  <td class="underline">ssp</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Please use **HTML Table** and avoid **`&nbsp;`**

Comment: Please Check @sandeep pradhan this code.
To avoid over usage of **&nbsp;**

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap all p.xN elements with div that will have class e.g. "move_right" that will have `padding-left: 10%;`

I hope this is what you wanted.

Included code.

```
<html>
<style>
  .email-container2 {
    border: 3px solid gray;
  }

  span.name {
    color: blue
  }

  .bottom-border {
    border-bottom: 30px solid blue;
  }

  .bottom-border1 {
    border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
  }

  .underline {
    text-decoration-line: underline;
    text-decoration-color: blue;
  }

  .email-container1 {
    border: 3px solid gray;
  }

  .right {
    margin-left: 80%;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  .move_left {
    padding-left: 10%;
  }

  p.x1 {
  }

  p.x2 {}

  p.x3 {
    ;
  }

  p.x4 {
    text-align: right;
  }

  p.x5 {}

  .img-container {
    text-align: left;
    height="20";
    width="20";
  }

  .img-container1 {
    text-align: right;
    width="100";
  }
</style>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="email-container">
    <div class="bottom-border">
      <div class="bottom-border1">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="row" style="width:100%">
            <div class="img-container" style="width:50%">
              <img src=https://careers.electronicsforu.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/tata-steel-logo.jpg alt="Airplane">
            </div>
            <div class="img-container1" style="width:50%">
              <img src=https://privatecdn.sharepointonline.com/tslin.sharepoint.com/sites/BoardingPass-Aviation/SiteAssets/SitePages/BoardingPass-Aviation/82731TataSteel_Aviation.jpg>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br />
          <div>
            <div class="email-container1" style="background-color:powderblue;">
              <h4 align="center">
                TATA STEEL AVIATION SERVICES</h2>
                <h2 style="color:blue" align="center"> Boarding Pass</h2>
                <div class="move_left">
                  <p class="x5" style="font-size:28px" ;> Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; <u><strong><span class="name">@{items('Apply_to_each')?['Date']}</span></strong></u></p>
                  <p class="x1" style="font-size:28px">Name: &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <u class="underline"><strong><span class="name">@{items('Apply_to_each')?['Name1']}</span></strong></u></p>
                  <p class="x2" style="font-size:28px">Aircraft Regn: &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<u class="underline"><strong><span class="name">@{items('Apply_to_each')?['AircraftRegn']?['Value']}</span></strong></u></p>
                  <p class="x3" style="font-size:28px">Sector: &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <u class="underline"><strong><span class="name">@{items('Apply_to_each')?['Sector']}</strong></span></u></p>
                  <p class="x4" style="font-size:22px">Signature: <u><strong><span class="name">@{items('Apply_to_each')?['Signature']}</span></strong></u></p>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```